# iOS - Getting Captcha Every Time When Sharing to Facebook using ShareKit

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

We are using ShareKit, an excellent open source framework for integrating social sharing services into iOS apps. We have been seeing lately that sharing to FaceBook triggers a captcha prior to submission almost every time. Needless to say, this experience is not what we want to offer our users.

In addition to that, if the user has keyed in any additional text or edited the post, receiving the captcha will ignore the extra text and only post the text that was pre-filled by the app when it popped the FBConnect dialog.

Has anyone else run across this? Is there some activity that might be causing the captcha to pop up that Facebook might consider a red flag?

As background, this app has been in the app store for almost a year, and this is the first time we're seeing this behavior.

Comment: We switched to a different (more updated) fork of ShareKit and the problem went away. This fork uses a more updated way of connecting to Facebook (https://github.com/troppoli/ShareKit)

Comment: Ill give that a try.... I feel like I tried that one once before.

Comment: Whenever I use this fork facebook fails to post. I click share, facebook, it launches the facebook app, redirects to my app, and after doing some debugging is returning an "unknown error" in the query. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you set up the handlers in your app delegate to accept the return call?

Comment: Yea I have those added. Those handlers are what call "handleOpenURL" in Facebook.m which is where I am receiving the error

Answer (score 0):

The captcha being required is likely related to the content you're posting - this is especially likely if you're on a shared domain with many other apps or websites - try sharing the individual links and images manually on Facebook.com to see if any throw a captcha there.

The other issue, that the content is partially lost after the captcha sounds like it could be a bug, you should file it at Facebook's API bug tracker at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net with repro instructions